# How to synchronously get a document with Mongoose?

Tags: javascript

I would like to store the value of a counter on a MongoDB database. At the server creation I need to get this counter value. If the database is empty, I create one document and return it, otherwise I fetch the document.

The problem is that the `count` method is asynchronous. And by the time express is launched, the value of `myCounter` is still `null`. How should I modify this code to create `myCounter`?

```
import express from 'express'
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose'

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test')

var CounterSchema = new Schema({ value: Number })    
CounterSchema.methods.increment = function (cb) { this.value++; this.save() }    
var Counter = mongoose.model('Counter', CounterSchema)

var myCounter = null

Counter.count({}, (err, count) => {
  if (err) { return }
  if (!count) {
    myCounter = Counter({value: 0})
    return
  }
  if (count > 1) { return }
  Counter.findOne({}, {}, {}, (err, post) => {
    if (err) { return }
    myCounter = post
  })
})

console.log(myCounter) // Is still null :(

var app = express()    
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  myCounter.increment() // Error if the request is quickly sent after the server start
  res.json(myCounter.value)
})    
app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try like this

```
import express from 'express'
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose'

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test')

var CounterSchema = new Schema({ value: Number })    
CounterSchema.methods.increment = function (cb) { this.value++ }    
var Counter = mongoose.model('Counter', CounterSchema)


console.log(myCounter) // Is still null :(

var myCounter = null

var app = express()

app.listen(3000,async () => {

  await Counter.count({}, (err, count) => {
    if (err) { return }
    if (!count) {
      myCounter = Counter({value: 0})
      return
    }
    if (count > 1) { return }
    Counter.findOne({}, {}, {}, (err, post) => {
      if (err) { return }
      instance = post
    })
  })
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      myCounter.increment()
      res.json(myCounter.value)
  })
})
```

Here we assign the myCounter variable right after the server got created asynchronously, we make the code work synchronously using the **await** keyword.

Comment: It looks nice, but I still get the same issue. When I send a request quickly after starting the server I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'increment' of null`

Comment: try adding the app.get() inside app.listen(). It should work.

Comment: The initial idea is not keep the API at the first level

Comment: You can either put the myCounter assignment inside app.listen(), or you can add the app.listen() inside the .then() of Counter.count()